# Is there an Equivalent of "proc surveylogistic" in R?

Tags: r, logistic, sas

A colleague told me about "proc surveylogistic" in SAS -- [see details here](http://bit.ly/1TB4y9s) -- is there an equivalent function in R?

Comment: Some explanation of what you want might help here. (And your link goes straight to the page on the TEST statement, which isn't very useful.)

Comment: @Scortchi sorry about that ... let me correct it -- I thought I linked it correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  You will want to use the svyglm function within the survey package.  It fits generalized linear models to data from a complex survey design.  See the svyglm page here:  http://r-survey.r-forge.r-project.org/survey/html/svyglm.html

Also, you will likely find the survey package and Thomas Lumley's book, Complex Surveys: a guide to analysis using R a valuable resource as you work through other analyses which make use of complex survey samples:  http://r-survey.r-forge.r-project.org/svybook/.